# Generate script creation postgres_fdw

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

We use postgres_fdw and we have many servers created and many schema imported. Each time we need to refresh the data of an environment by another environment we need to manually update all the servers to link to the right server.

Is there a way we can generate the script of the foreign server creation and import schema for all the databases in a server?

Thank you

Comment: You can  create a routine using PLPGSQL  to do that

Comment: What specifically needs to be refreshed?  Do your hosts keep changing their names?

Comment: @jjanes the host name changes since we replace the database by the backup of the database of another environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to recreate the server and reimport the schema.  You can just change the hostname on the existing server.

```
ALTER SERVER foo OPTIONS (SET host 'newhost');
```

But why not just use dns to repoint the server name to the new machine?